# Single Perceptron Implementation

Tags: code-golf

### Challenge

Train a single perceptron with 2 inputs and 1 output.

[image]

**Step 1:** Initialize the weights

**Step 2:** Calculate the output

For inputs: [i1, i2, ..., in] and  weights: [w1, w2, ..., wn] the output is:

```
i1 * w1 + i2 * w2 + ... + in * wn
```

**Step 3:** Apply activation function on the output (i.e sigmoid)

**Step 4:** Update the weights

```
w(t + 1) = w(t) + r * (desired_output - actual_output)
```

Where r: learning rate

**Step 5** Repeat steps 2, 3 and 4

### Input

**iterations**: how many times you repeat steps 2, 3 and 4
**input**: a list with 2 input values i.e. `[1, 0]` 
**output**: the desired output
**learning_rate**: the learning rate i.e.`0.3`

### Output

It should print the last calculated output. Keep in mind this should be very close to the desired output i.e `0.96564545` for desired output `1`

### Example

For input (training for XOR):

```
1000, [1 0], 1, 0.3
```

The output should be:

```
0.9966304251639512
```

**Note** The output will never be the same even for identical test cases due to random weights initialization.

Here's some non-golfed code in Python for this test case:

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##XZA9a8QwDIbn@FcIuthXXxr3tkKHTt0LnUIo5uxcBBfb@JQm1z@f2vmg0MWyJPS8ehXu1Hl3mrEPPhJE7Yzv2Zb1mrqZGdsCRY2OI9koAV0YSIIfaIlRvDBWPMDHMoo/FqizMFq8dHRjxQivUK/YcnDY@tjzSioB6QdfCZY1L5Y/i4YVrMhV/KtmxcQvUidJvFta4PpM@rotkBomSSxL1VVzGNMDj1uucq6aff4thOt9J@C3JvQO2sGdlw@/4aX3aMSGVPAEXCVWPkNpp8CPRoid9RmMpn9eV7MwpZkIB@DrhnAEs9qdsrERmnSvENERT1rzelpVVZWEWkmoGgk5lCcx/wI)

### Rules

1. The inputs and outputs of the perceptron are fixed to: 2 and 1 respectively.
2. The output needs to be close to the desired output (see example).
3. You can use any activation function you want, just mention it.

Comment: To make the challenge self-contained, can you give examples of activation functions and list the constraints such a function must follow?

Comment: It seems that the identity function is an activation function according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activation_function); I suspect it would be golfiest to just use that.

Comment: Also the constraint "should be very close" is too vague IMO... maybe restrict to a list of activation functions? and I was about to say the same thing as @Giuseppe...

Comment: Sorry everyone, this is my first attempt.

Comment: @DimChtz no worries! We typically suggest posting challenges in [The Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) for a while so they can get some feedback. My suggestions for now (unless you want to delete this temporarily and try it there first) are to specify a list of activation functions we're allowed to use, and remove Rule #2 since the final output should be the result of the selected Activation function and the weights.

Comment: Actually, I have another question; you say "initialize the weights" -- how are we supposed to do that? Are there constraints on the weights? Your example uses uniform random numbers in [0,1] but could we use a different distribution? etc.

Comment: Random? What's the distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>121</s> 110  bytes

Same as TFled. A "golfed" version of the example.

*-11 bytes from @Arnauld*

```javascript
with(Math)f=(a,[b,B],c,d)=>(g=w=>a--?g(w.map(_=>_+d*(c-(y=1/(1+exp(B*w[1]-b*w[0])))))):y)([random(),random()])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcbLCoMwEEDRX3E5oxOb0F0hCu77BSFITHwVNaLS1K9PH9C7Ofdhnma327gebPGujTGMxwB3cwzYSTCkGqo0WXIoC@hlkIVhrOwh5LNZoZZFnbkULINTiguIrH2tUKVBCc2aD1zjr9uJoDazOD8D0n80RuuX3U9tPvkeOhCcc0qUoIRrSr7kV8T4Bg)

Comment: [110 bytes](https://tio.run/##NcbLCoMwEEDRX3E5oxOb0F0hCu77BSFITHwVNaLS1K9PH9C7Ofdhnma327gebPGujTGMxwB3cwzYSTCkGqo0WXIoC@hlkIVhrOwh5LNZoZZFnbkULINTiguIrH2tUKVBCc2aD1zjr9uJoDazOD8D0n80RuuX3U9tPvkeOhCcc0qUoIRrSr7kV8T4Bg). Most bytes are saved by going recursive and splitting the 2nd argument right away. The `with(Math)f=` trick only saves 1 byte.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 136 bytes

```python
from random import*
import math
def f(n,(i,I),o,r):w,W=random(),random();exec"d=1/(1+math.exp(-i*w-I*W));c=r*(o-d);w+=c;W+=c;"*n;print d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcuxDoMgFIXh3ae4cbrg1UK7lfAAPoFD08EIRAaBEBLt09Ma0@V8Z/nTp6wx3Gt1OW6Q52B@@C3FXHhzCdtc1sZYBw4DoaeRUaTMnjtN@iqQ0f8oe9ilNVreUHZnOdgjYe/53o98YkwtOnOMvWFq7/SipnNaHlTKPhQw1aEUQhC8JIF4E5wMD1a/)

Basically just a golfed version of the example